# How to prevent a closing tab QTabWidget? PyQT4

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qtabwidget

With this code:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.tabWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("tabCloseRequested(int)"),
                       self.tabWidget.removeTab)
```

I can close any tab QTabWidget, and the names of these tabs are:

`work_1`

`work_2`

`work_3`

But I want the tab **work_1** never closes.

Use Index did not work for two reasons:

- **The tabs can be dynamically moved by this code:**

  ```
  self.tabWidget.setMovable (True)
  ```

That makes the Index are constantly changing.

- **The user has the ability to add new tabs.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs can be identified by their widgets, and the widgets can be identified by their `objectName` (or some other unique attribute):

```
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(sef.removeTab)
        ...

    def removeTab(self, index):
        widget = self.tabWidget.widget(index)
        if widget is not None and widget.objectName() != 'work_1':
            self.tabWidget.removeTab(index)
```

or perhaps more simply:

```
        if widget is not None and widget is not self.work_1:
            self.tabWidget.removeTab(index)
```

Comment: Yes, if he had thought of the objectName but did not know how to connect.
Thanks for your help.